# Morning vs Evening Sun?

Tags: sunlight

I am going to be planting some flowers into a few flower beds in my house. The sun essentially rises in the back of my house and sets in the front. So this gives about half/half as far as the sun goes (With the south flowerbed getting slightly more sun since it's not up against the house).

Should this matter as far as partial/full sun? I'd imagine each side is getting at least 4-6 (Which is considered full sun right?) or should I go with plants that can mainly do partial sun?

(BTW plants that need full shade won't be totally screwed over if they get 4-6 hours of sun but spend a good amount of time in the shade right? Same thing for Plants that need full sun?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plants that need full shade need full shade - half a day's sun won't do them any good, especially not if they're in full sun between 11-3 pm.  Others prefer what's known as 'dappled' shade, meaning they're partially shaded usually by other plants, such as a tree above, although full sun for an hour or two mornings and evenings is usually acceptable. Otherwise, most plants will do fine with 4-6 hours of sun, on the assumption you're not growing vegetables - many of those require 8-10 hours a day. 'Full sun' is taken to mean at least six hours per day.

Comment: And there is "high" shade ; Trees  with foliage 75' to 100'  up. Much light but little sun gets to the ground . Typical of southern ( US ) pines , azaleas love this situation ( and acid needles and bark. )

Comment: I have a shaded spot near my house that is always in the shade, but the full sun is right next to it always....is this still considered full shade?  (since the surrounding areas are always in full sun)

Comment: Its full shade -the ambient light levels might be higher, but its still full shade @msmith1114